# How does patenting regarding Bluetooth technology work?

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement, patent-applications

First of all, thanks for your time!

Bluetooth technology basically uses a short radio to wireless connect two devices.

I was wondering if it is possible to patent the use of Bluetooth technology for a specific device, since it could in a way be considered an abstract idea..?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are eligible to get a patent if the new combination (blue-tooth enabled device) is useful (has a useful purpose, and is not a trivial entertainment, perpetual motion machine, article of nature or abstract idea), novel (doesn't already exist) and is not obvious when considering the present state of art. Since the device presently exists, and your post postulates the existence of Bluetooth applicability to the device, obviousness may be the tough hurdle. On the other hand, if there is a particularly difficult problem to overcome in applying Bluetooth control to the device, or if a Bluetooth enabled device yields the device that's able to perform new or improved or enhanced functions in a way that ordinary remote control would not, I would say you might have a shot. There are other indications of non-obviousness that may apply in your case, so if you are serious, consult a lawyer.

Comment: Thank you so much "PGilm." You really explained that perfectly! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP’s question was directed more to whether his invention would pass muster under the Alice/Mayo framework, and not so much about novelty/non-obviousness.  Of course, without actually seeing a claim, one cannot make a determination as to whether the claim recites “an abstract idea without significantly more”.

As an aside, Bluetooth is a registered trademark/tradename, and so a claim reciting that term may be indefinite under 112b.

Comment: A reference to the specific Bluetooth specification in the application would take care of indefiniteness. In any case a claim would want to characterize the radio transmission technique used in a broader way than saying Bluetooth. Maybe it could be done with WiFi or done with some not yet invented RF protocol.